play-pac4j SAML profile not in session after redirect
Very odd issue with IDP-initiated SAML auth.  The user profile is somehow lost after a redirect.  SAML assertion checks out.  I extract the UserProfile and save it in the Play session and then do a simple redirect.
final ProfileManager manager = new ProfileManager(playWebContext, playWebContext.getSessionStore());
manager.save(true, userProfile, false);

Then I do a redirect where the user authentication is added to the session.  But the profile is not in the session.
final ProfileManager manager = new ProfileManager(context, context.sessionStore);
Optional<CommonProfile> optionalProfile = manager.getProfile(CommonProfile.class);

This issue triggers an SP-initiated flow which is the same as the above - same exact code, yet that works fine.  The redirect occurs and the profile is there in the session as expected.
This seems to occur with any IDP.  I have tested in my qa environment with Entra IDP and locally with KeyCloak.
I have confirmed that profile is saved in the session.  After I save it I have some debug code to pull it out again.  The profile is there.  But again, it's lost once the redirect happens.
